# ADPlus 'some selected processes are not running', except they are. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2003, adplus

Trying to run ADPlus on a WindowsServiceHost.exe that is currently running on a production Windows 2003 server, however, when I try to run the AD, it tells me the process isn't running. Why?

My command: %filepath%\ADPlus -hang -pn %filepath%\WindowsServiceHost.exe -o %Output Directory%

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was the filepath for the .exe. It's not needed and it ran once the filepath was omitted.